# Thread blocks main Thread in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

...
....

```
    ping_thread = Thread.new {
        loop do
            sleep 2
            ping
        end
    }
    ping_thread.join

    puts "TEST"
```

...
....

it executes the ping function but does not move on printing the "TEST" statement. The ping function has a simple "puts "PING"" statement inside of it. I want the ping_thread to run as a background thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.new` will start your thread running in the background automatically, and `Thread#join` will block until that thread finishes its job. So normally, joining the thread is the *last* thing you do, when the main execution thread is done doing its work.

Try the following code and see if it does what you want:

```
ping_thread = Thread.new {
    loop do
        sleep 2
        puts "ping"
    end
}

puts "TEST"

ping_thread.join
```

Note that if you *don't* join the thead in the end, it will die when the main execution thread completes its work, so that join is necessary.

Comment: I just need the thread to start at that time, as a background process, not at the end

Comment: in other words I want the thread to start and then the programs continues normally

Comment: That's what the example does :-)

Answer (score 1):

`.join` means *`just wait here until thread is dead`*